# How do I horizontally compress or unstretch paragraph text?

Tags: hyperref, urls, white-space

My references section sometimes shows a lot of whitespace between words that I would like to remove.

For example, in the following screenshot, I would like to remove the extra spaces within the text "Describing a link":

[image]

I know that I can use mbox (for example, `\mbox{Describing a link}`), but I'd like to apply some option to avoid this globally.

**Update**: The main answer worked for `\url`, but now I get the same issue when using `\href`:

```
\bibitem{Reference2} Some Name, \href{mailto:testlongname@example.com}{testlongname@example.com}
```

[image]

Here is the full example document:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{xurl} % Added based on the initial answer
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true, urlcolor = blue, linkcolor = blue, citecolor = blue}

\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\itshape}

\title{Test Article}
\author{Test Author}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
\noindent
Test abstract.
      \newline\newline
    \end{abstract}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

\section{Section1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\cite{Reference1}, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce maximus nisi ligula. Morbi laoreet ex ligula, vitae lobortis purus mattis vel. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec ac metus ut turpis mollis placerat et nec enim. Duis tristique nibh maximus faucibus facilisis. Praesent in consequat leo. Maecenas condimentum ex rhoncus, elementum diam vel, malesuada ante. Fusce pulvinar, mauris pretium placerat venenatis, lectus ex tempus lacus, id suscipit libero lorem eu augue. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

\section{Section2}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce maximus nisi ligula. Morbi laoreet ex ligula, vitae lobortis purus mattis vel. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec ac metus ut turpis mollis placerat et nec enim. Duis tristique nibh maximus faucibus facilisis. Praesent in consequat leo. Maecenas condimentum ex rhoncus, elementum diam vel, malesuada ante. Fusce pulvinar, mauris pretium placerat venenatis, lectus ex tempus lacus, id suscipit libero lorem eu augue. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Reference1} Describing a link, \url{https://example.com/this_is_a_really_long_link_that_wraps_many_lines}
\bibitem{Reference2} Some Name, \href{mailto:testlongname@example.com}{testlongname@example.com}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, packages `url` and `xurl` are prepared to work with command `\url` but not with `\href{}{}`. Because the second parameter of `\href` is set as normal text you can try `\href{mailto:testlongname@example.com}{testlongname@example. com}` (I added an blank in the second parameter to allow there a break) ... But you need to this manually for each issue ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case you can simply add `\usepackage{xurl}` in your preamble. Be sure to call `xurl` before package `hyperref` (if you omit that, `hyperref` itself calls package `url` with the result you got ...)!

With the following code

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{xurl} % <===================================================
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true, urlcolor = blue, linkcolor = blue, citecolor = blue}

\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\itshape}

\title{Test Article}
\author{Test Author}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
\noindent
Test abstract.
      \newline\newline
    \end{abstract}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

\section{Section1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\cite{Reference1}, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce maximus nisi ligula. Morbi laoreet ex ligula, vitae lobortis purus mattis vel. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec ac metus ut turpis mollis placerat et nec enim. Duis tristique nibh maximus faucibus facilisis. Praesent in consequat leo. Maecenas condimentum ex rhoncus, elementum diam vel, malesuada ante. Fusce pulvinar, mauris pretium placerat venenatis, lectus ex tempus lacus, id suscipit libero lorem eu augue. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

\section{Section2}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce maximus nisi ligula. Morbi laoreet ex ligula, vitae lobortis purus mattis vel. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec ac metus ut turpis mollis placerat et nec enim. Duis tristique nibh maximus faucibus facilisis. Praesent in consequat leo. Maecenas condimentum ex rhoncus, elementum diam vel, malesuada ante. Fusce pulvinar, mauris pretium placerat venenatis, lectus ex tempus lacus, id suscipit libero lorem eu augue. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Reference1} Describing a link, \url{https://example.com/this_is_a_really_long_link_that_wraps_many_lines}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

Comment: Update: The main answer worked for `\url`, but now I get the same issue when using `\href`. I updated the question and example document to show the new issue.